# Show that $f(x)=x^21_{C^c}(x)$ is Lebesgue measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let define $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ as follows:

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if  $$x$ \in \mathbb{C}$} \\
x^2, & \text{if $x$ $\notin \mathbb{C}$ }
\end{cases},$
where $\mathbb{C}$ is the Cantor set. Show $f$ is  Lebesgue measurable function.

I know a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is called Lebesgue-measurable if preimages of Borel-measurable sets are Lebesgue-measurable. I think it is enough to show for any $a\geq 0$,
$f^{-1}(a,\infty)=\{ f>a \}=\{x\in [0,1]\mid f(x)>a \}$ is Lebesgue-measurable set. But I stuck here
$f^{-1}(a,\infty)=
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{C}^c &  a< 0\\
[0,1] & a\geq 0
\end{cases}.
$

Answer (score 4):

Well, $[0,1]=C\hspace{1mm}\cup C^{c} $ (I discourage you to use $\mathbb{C}$ for the cantor set) and you can write f as:
$$f(x)=0\cdot\chi_{C}(x)+x^{2}\chi_{C^{c}}$$
where by $\chi$ I mean the characteristic function of the set in subscript. The sum of measurable functions is measurable as well as the product, and polynomial functions are measurable.

Comment: More importantly, the product of measurable functions is measurable. The first summand is anyway zero :) already (+1) for discouraging that notation

Comment: correct, I should have wrote the same also for the product, thank you for the note.